# Query all posts where a meta key does not exist

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-meta

I am trying to get a query to retrieve all the posts where a specific `meta_key` does not exist and then create it.

I am having problems finding those posts as the query I am testing does not seem to work.

Here is the code I am using to try to get those posts:

```
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 18,
   'cat'=>1955,
   'post_status'=>'publish',
   'meta_query' => array(
                  array(
                     'key' => 'colors',
                     'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                  ),
   ));      

query_posts($args);
```

This returns nothing if there are no posts with the key `colors`, but returns they `ids` of the posts with the key `colors` whenever that key is present (the opposite of what I need). I tried with `EXIST` instead but no luck.

If someone can tip me on the correct way of creating a query like the one I need I will appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: Hi,sorry for the omission. I am using v3.5

Comment: It seems as though that type of query (with compare set to NOT EXISTS) was added in 3.5, so it should work as it is, as far as I can see. It would be easy to do it via custom SELECT query, though...

Comment: Thanks I will try using select. I must learn before which tables to query and how to conform the query though :(

Comment: Very strange. I can't spot a problem with that code and you are using 3.5+, which is why I asked. Have you actually looked at the database to confirm that your data is being inserted the way you think it is?

Comment: Have you tried 'EXISTS'? You mentioned 'EXIST' but I believe compare only accepts 'EXISTS' with an 'S' on the end.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Unfortunately EXISTS didn't work either. I will go to the query option I think.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I did some more testing with this, and honestly can't find a reason it wouldn't work (unless the code above is just a snippet and the real code fits on my examples below). I did, however, discover a couple of things that might lead you in the right direction.

1) By itself, this meta query is the equivalent of "colors IS NULL", i.e. it'll return the posts which don't have that key set in the postmeta table. This is the case shown above, and it should've worked.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
     'key' => 'colors',
     'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' // this should work...
    ),
)
```

2) Prior to WordPress 3.9, establishing the 'relation' index to 'OR' changes this condition. It returns the opposite. Don't ask me why. This is especially important when doing multiple meta queries. That means that is not initially possible to do a query for posts that have 'colors' key set to 'blue' (or whatever) or not set at all. The query below will ignore the first condition and return only those that match the second condition.

```
'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
     'key' => 'colors',
     'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' // doesn't work
    ),
    array(
     'key' => 'colors',
     'value' => 'blue'
    )
)
```

3) However, we can fool WordPress into using the first condition if we set the 'value'. It doesn't need a relevant value (it's ignored, as far as I know), but it **needs to be set** in order for the `NOT EXISTS` condition to have any effect.

```
'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
     'key' => 'colors',
     'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', // works!
     'value' => '' // This is ignored, but is necessary...
    ),
    array(
     'key' => 'colors',
     'value' => 'blue'
    )
)
```

This was true up until WordPress 3.9. If you're still using an older version, this is a viable workaround.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for the delay. I ended up using a query, but I will be testing your solution in the following hours so I can switch back and maybe if this work we can help some other. I will let you know as soon as I can check it. Thanks again

Comment: Well written and confirmed that adding an empty value returns expected results. I'd say it's unintentional, may be worth a look at trac.wordpress.org to see if there's already a ticket, if not, this is reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and solution to trick WP :) Did take some time to get here - but now I want to click upvote for at least 10 times (if only I could ;))

Comment: If I use compare EXISTS, value is unfortunately not ignored in newer versions of WP (tested in 4.2.2)

Comment: Be aware of an `orderby meta_key`  that may also be in your query! Wordpress will hardcode `WHERE meta_key = value` for a meta orderby as well!

Comment: The `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` "bug" which required you to specify a value, was fixed in WP 3.9

Comment: trex005 is right: "(Note: Due to bug #23268, value is required for NOT EXISTS comparisons to work correctly prior to 3.9. You must supply some string for the value parameter. An empty string or NULL will NOT work. However, any other string will do the trick and will NOT show up in your SQL when using NOT EXISTS. Need inspiration? How about 'bug #23268'.)"

Comment: The 'OR' combination as showed above at 3) works for me too, but it is very inperformant and results in heavy load times over 30 seconds. (using Woocommerce with more than 9000 products)

Answer (score 20):

Using a custom query, this worked for me:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts as posts
            WHERE   posts.post_type     = 'post'
            AND NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta`
               WHERE `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = "your_meta_key"
                AND `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`=posts.ID
            )
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding a relation makes it work, even though there's only one clause

```
'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
     'key' => 'colors',
     'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' 
    )
)
```