# WP_Query, tax_query and term_meta: How to?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, get-posts, tax-query, term-meta

I have a custom post type product (wine). Each of the following is a custom taxonomy:

- Vintage (Year of harvesting) [only one per wine]
- Family (Grape variety) [may be more than one]
- Size (Bottle Size) [only one per product]

In the single product view of a wine I want to do the following queries:

1) Find all wines which have the **same family**, **same size** but are from a **different vintage**

2) Find all wines (post type: product) which are in the **same family** AND have the **same vintage** AND have a **different size**.

Now the problem: The **numeric year** is a custom term meta property of the **vintage term**. The **numeric bottle size** is a custom term meta property of the size term.

For the first query I have tried the following:

```
                $other_years = get_posts(array(
                  'post_type' => 'product',
                  'numberposts' => -1,
                  'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'family',
                      'field' => 'id',
                      'terms' => $family->term_id, // Where term_id of Term 1 is "1".
                      'include_children' => false
                    ),
                    array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'size',
                      'field' => 'id',
                      'terms' => $size->term_id, // Where term_id of Term 1 is "1".
                      'include_children' => false
                    ),
                    array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'vintage',
                      'field' => 'id',
                      'terms' => array($vintage->term_id), // Where term_id of Term 1 is "1".
                      'include_children' => false,
                      'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                    ),
                  )
                ));
```

**It works.** However: Instead of comparing the ***term_id*** (here: term id of vintage) I would like to compare if the term custom meta value (year_numeric) is different.

Is there any possibility to do such a query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to achieve that within a single WP_Query, so you'll have to first get a list of term_ids which have a **different year** than the one in question.

I think with the following you'll come quite close. (don't have a env to test right away)

```
$other_years_terms = get_terms(
     'taxonomy'     =>  'vintage',
     'meta_key'     =>  'year_numeric',
     'meta_value'   =>  $the_current_wine_year,   // You'll have to figure that out
     'meta_compare' =>  '!=',
     'fields'       =>  'ids'
);

$other_years_posts = get_posts(array(
              'post_type' => 'product',
              'numberposts' => -1,
              'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'family',
                  'field' => 'id',
                  'terms' => $family->term_id, // Where term_id of Term 1 is "1".
                  'include_children' => false
                ),
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'size',
                  'field' => 'id',
                  'terms' => $size->term_id, // Where term_id of Term 1 is "1".
                  'include_children' => false
                ),
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'vintage',
                  'field' => 'term_id',
                  'terms' => $other_years_terms,
                ),
              )
            ));
```

Comment: Some research was also done by me and I guess you are right. This is the only way currently. However I think they should add this functionality as it certainly exists (with posts (meta_query)).

Comment: Created a feature request maybe they implement it: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41265

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are checking for when a meta key does not exist.

Please refer to this similar question: [query all posts where a meta key does not exist](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80303/query-all-posts-where-a-meta-key-does-not-exist)